# how can I implement nat in Linux now?

Tags: nat, iproute2

I used to be able to do it with iproute2 (ip rule and ip route), but it's been deprecated.

I now found tc-nat. From the man-page:

```
 tc ... action nat DIRECTION OLD NEW
```

However, when using it:

```
Command "nat" is unknown, try "tc actions help".
```

What now? Go full-on nftables?

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, kernel 4.15.0-99-generic

Comment: There's Linux, Linux, and Linux. Which distro, and release number? Please click [edit] and add that to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did it with the firewall. As K7AYY alluded - there's many way to flay a feline - so what you're doing it in, and how you used to do it might help. I personally did it with firewalld front ending iptables, and the guide I used used for inspiration used raw iptables.

Comment: can be done with tc (dumb nat 1:1 ranges), iptables (2 methods: dynamic or 1:1 ranges), nftables (2 methods: dynamic, tc-like dumb nat and soon a 3rd 1:1 ranges like iptables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to use `iptables` (firewall rules). Here's the script I use (NAT as "masquerade", which uses IP address of the network interface):

```
#!/bin/bash

# masquerade $1 (e.g. eth0, ppp0) as $2 (default wlan0)

INTIF="$1"
EXTIF=${2:-wlan0}

echo $INTIF $EXTIF

modprobe nf_conntrack
modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv4
modprobe nf_nat
modprobe iptable_nat  

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_dynaddr

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

You may not need all this setup at the beginning, but it doesn't hurt.

That's the usual application for "sharing internet", if you need a more complicated NAT setup, please edit the question and describe details.

Comment: I got it. All I wanted to know was if I could do with some iproute2 utility (maybe I was getting tc wrong), or if I had to use the firewall. I'll use nftables, since IPtables has been supplanted by it in many places.